# searching.wordpress via json

Tags: json, wordpress

I need to get author id via wordpress json api.

e.g :

> http://eng.search.wordpress.com/?q=apple&page=2&s=date&f=json

The output is :

> [{"title":"Rumor: Ya se habla del lanzamiento del Samung Galaxy S IV
>   para marzo de
>   2013","link":"http://techyzmundo.com/2012/11/15/rumor-ya-se-habla-del-lanzamiento-del-samung-galaxy-s-iv-para-marzo-de-2013/","epoch_time":"1352993240","author":"Techyzmundo","guid":"http://techyzmundo.com/2012/11/15/rumor-ya-se-habla-del-lanzamiento-del-samung-galaxy-s-iv-para-marzo-de-2013/","content":"Al
>   mismo estilo que Apple, no ha pasado ni 6 meses hay se est\u00e1
>   hablando de una nueva versi\u00f3n del Equipo bandera de Samsung para
>   marzo del pr\u00f3ximo […]"},{"title..........."

There isn't author id in the json output. How can I send a request in wordpress searching url for author id ?

Comment: what is your use case? you have the author username and from that you might be able todo whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP User Query class for this (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) and because you've got the user nicename, you can use this as a query parameter.

For example:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('nicename' => 'Techyzmundo'));
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: I doesn't want to your suggestion. Your example is to get post of a spesific users. I just want to get authorid who is writing post in response.